# (C++) Whether I should put a constant in a namespace or not

Tags: c++, namespaces

I am coming from Java background and trying to fix some c++ code that's a legacy.

The structure is like

```
namespace ABC {
namespape CDE {

using namespace XYZ; //I do not know about this

//class CCC
CCC::CCC(...) {};

void CCC::c1(...) {...};
void CCC::c2(...) {...};
void CCC::c3(...) {...};
}
}
```

and I need to add a constant, but I'm not sure where it should go.

```
namespace ABC {
namespape CDE {

namespace {
const DateTime today = 20200508;
} // 1st way

const DateTime today = 20200508;  // 2nd way

using namespace XYZ; //I do not know about this


//class CCC
CCC::CCC(...) {};

void CCC::c1(...) {... today ...};
void CCC::c2(...) {... today ...};
void CCC::c3(...) {... today ...};
}
}
```

So all the functions in this CCC class are dealing with this date and I would like to create a const.

1) Where is it more appropriate, 1st way or 2nd way?

2) What are the differences are between these two places? Both way it built without errors, FYI.

3) Should this const declaration go before or after this line: using namespace XYZ?

Thank you!

Comment: 3) What you like better. 1/2) I don't see a good reason for an additional anonymous namespace. What shall the anonymous namespace be for? What shall it tell me as a reader of the file?

Comment: First way uses an anonymous namespace to lock `ABC::CED::today` in this one [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). It won't come into conflict with `ABC::CED::today`s defined in other translation units. This can be useful even though in this case the `ABC` and `CDE` namespaces probably make collisions unlikely. In general, try to keep definitions as tightly scoped as possible.

Comment: Not much, but I see lots of that anonymous namespace being used in this code base (after namespace ABC and namespace CDE) so I was wondering that too. But since I'm a novice I wasn't sure if there's special meaning to it or not...